# Create x,y points with a radius that best fill a polygon

Tags: polygon, coordinates, mapinfo

I am looking to best fill a polygon with non-overlapping circles of a specified radius and then extract the x,y points from a table.  Is there a way to do this in MapInfo without specifically picking the x,y coordinates?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [List of combinatorial computational geometry topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_combinatorial_computational_geometry_topics) and [Geometric algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Geometric_algorithms) and [Circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing). Once you found an appropriate algorithm you can think about implementation.